# PHP router only triggers on index, but not other URI's

Tags: php, routes, url-routing

I'm using the Bramus PHP router for my application, but it only seems to work on the index route which is `/`. Here's the piece of code that won't work:

```
public function handle(): Response
{
    $response = null;
    
    $request = new Request($_REQUEST);
    $uri = $request->getRequestUri();

    $container = $this->configureContainer();
    $renderer = new RendererFactory();
    $router = $this->configureRouter();

    $controllerFactory = new ControllerFactory();
    $controller = $controllerFactory->create($request, $container, $renderer, $uri);

    $router->get($uri, function () use ($uri, $controller, &$response) {
        $response = $controller->get();
    });

    $router->run();

    return $response;
}
```

So when I go to the homepage, it works fine and returns the response with the correct value. However, when I go to say `/about-us`, the `$router->get()` never fires at all. It doesn't execute the anonymous function inside. Even replacing the `$uri` parameter with a hardcoded string like `$router->get('/about-us'...)` doesn't make the anonymous function execute.

I confirmed that the `ControllerFactory` does in fact return the right controller, so if the `$router->get()` fires, the `get()` method is in there and the `$response` should not be null. But now I get an error saying `$response` is null because the `$router->get()` won't fire.

What's the mistake I'm missing here? How can the index route work perfectly fine, but the router won't accept another route?

*Edit Did some digging and added a var_dump to the Bramus Router*

I added a var_dump() in the `handle` function inside the package itself, and it always says that the result of `$this->getCurrentUri()` is `/`, and not the URI in the browser.

My .htaccess is in the root directory and I redirect all requests to `/public/index.php`. Maybe that's the culprit? But I don't know how to fix it. My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add `$router->setBasePath('/');`, and my folder structure and .htaccess config made the router go crazy.